# SalesForce - How to get list on tables/entities with their numbers of records using SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-communities

I would like to push all NOT EMPTY objects/entities/tables from SalesForce to the Azure Data Lake.
I'm using SOQL, and the only way is to use
`"SELECT QualifiedApiName AS TableName FROM EntityDefinition"` within Lookup activity and then
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @{item()}`  which is not good from performance prospective.

Is it the better way to get all non-empty entities ?

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful when you say "all not empty". You can get many system tables (do you care about Apex classes? Chatter posts? Account change event capture? past versions of uploaded files?)

COUNTs suck a bit but if you can hook up a piece of code to run a REST API call you can get results similar to Salesforce Setup -> Storage Usage.

It's just a HTTP GET + session id passed as a header.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_record_count.htm

If you have hard time including it in your process - maybe ask developer to build a snapshot of this running every night, writing to a helper table... and you'd start your process by querying that table? Not great but well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. "You can get many system tables (do you care about Apex classes? Chatter posts? Account change event capture? past versions of uploaded files?)" -  Of course I don't need that system trash, what I need are the real entities. Thanks for your link, BUT I have to pass the list of objects as a parameter there, but list of objects this is what I'm looking for ;)

Comment: No you don't, the parameter is optional. Try without it and if it's very slow - `SELECT QualifiedApiName
FROM EntityDefinition
WHERE IsCustomizable = true AND IsCustomSetting = false` is decent way to "help" it focus on objects you need.